# Keyboard automatically pops up when clicking searchable spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, keyboard-events

I am using searchable spinner by miteshpithadiya the GitHub link is

[`https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner`](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner)

The spinner works great but it the soft keyboard keeps popping up when the spinner is clicked.
I want to have been searching for a solution but have not found any

I have tried using on touch event but hat has only removed the searchable spinner feature and left the default spinner

Kindly recommend a solution or another searchable spinner

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But is keyboard still appears on click on spinner then it might be good to use another searchable spinner I used this one and it works seemlessly

```
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
```

Add this style -

```
<style name="Theme.UserDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
</style>
```

Add in your spinner xml part.

Comment: Tried this the same but there is no change. have put this issue in the GitHub repository

Comment: I am using the same spinner. the search and selection work all fine but the keyboard popup is a put-off. any other spinners you recommend

Comment: Then use com.toptoche.searchablespinner this searchable spinner.

Comment: I am using it. this is the link to same spinner https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

Comment: Ohh I didn't noticed it.. Well as what specific issue you/re facing like from your question I'm guessing you not want to open the keyboard until your edit text in searchable spinner click now what happen is it opens as soon as spinner appear am I right ?

Comment: that exactly what I am facing. I had declared the spinner as default spinner but changing it to SearchableSpinner let me set the title. But the keyboard still comes up on touch. I am guessing that it focuses on the search that why the keyboard keeps coming up on opening because when I click on the back button the focus goes out of the search and the keyboard disappears

Comment: Correct it come in focus when as soon you click on spinner see you need to define a style in your style file assign it to the spinner in your xml. See my answer I edited that.

Comment: thanks for the effort bro. appreciate it. the style (colour) is affected but not the focus on the search i have also tried to try other styles like android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusedByDefault="false" android:screenReaderFocusable="false" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" but none of them affect the keyboard

Comment: I found out why this was taking place. the issue is with the phone. The device that I was testing was a moto phone. I also later tried on LeTV, Redmi and Samsung and without any additional styles and code. it works fine. this only happens in moto phones

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: does this go on the onCreate method?

Comment: You can add this when you are setting up the spinner

Comment: I have tried this code on the onCreate function and just before applying the array adapter to the spinner. Does not work in both cases